# How to overlay status bar and navigation bar from a Service? (android 4.4)

Tags: android, android-layout

**android 4.4**

I have a Service which is launched by Application (NOT an Activity).
When required, the Service needs to overlay the taskbar and navigation bar with a view.
How do I do it?
I tried

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
   PixelFormat.OPAQUE);

rootView = // inflate layout from xml file
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.addView(rootView, params);
```

This goes **behind** the taskbar and does not overlay it.

The android documentation https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html
requires using a DecorView obtained from getWindow().
My code will not compile since getWindow() does not exist.
How to overlay status bar and navigation bar from a Service? (android 4.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_BOOT_PROGRESS

Comment: What permission do I need for this?
I get WindowManager.BadTokenException for this, says permission denied for this window type.

Comment: NVM I found it, it's android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW.

Comment: It,s for system apps.